# How to mark if question is complete vs incomplete based on the page index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a form with 11 questions. Im trying to build a progress bar that updates an array of objects for each question and flags whether its complete or incomplete. I only want it to be complete if they click next. If they click back it should mark as incomplete. For example: If i'm on question 1, it should be incomplete, when I go to question 2 it becomes complete and so on. Same thing for going back. If im on question 3 it should be incomplete, if I go back to question 2, question 2 should mark as incomplete.

My code kinda works although for some reason if I click next, next, back I have to click back twice for it to properly update.

here is the code:

```
   const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

    const [progress, setProgress] = useState([
        { pageIndex: 0, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 1, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 2, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 3, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 4, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 5, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 6, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 7, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 8, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 9, completed: false },
        { pageIndex: 10, completed: false },
    ]);

    const handleNavButtonNext = () => {
        // Mark previous page as complete
        const newProgress = [...progress];
        newProgress[currentPage].completed = true;
        setProgress(newProgress);

        // Move to next page
        setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);

    };
    const handleNavButtonBack = () => {
        // Mark current page as incomplete
        const newProgress = [...progress];
        newProgress[currentPage].completed = false;
        setProgress(newProgress);

        // Move to previous page
        setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);

    };
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't have to create a new array every time. Just modify the original objects directly: `progress[currentPage].completed = true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press the back button, you make the current question incomplete, but you have to do the previous question as well.

```
const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(0);

const [progress, setProgress] = useState([
    { pageIndex: 0, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 1, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 2, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 3, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 4, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 5, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 6, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 7, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 8, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 9, completed: false },
    { pageIndex: 10, completed: false },
]);

const handleNavButtonNext = () => {
    // Mark previous page as complete
    const newProgress = [...progress];
    newProgress[currentPage].completed = true;
    setProgress(newProgress);

    // Move to next page
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);

};
const handleNavButtonBack = () => {
    // Mark current page as incomplete
    const newProgress = [...progress];
    newProgress[currentPage].completed = false;
    newProgress[currentPage-1].completed = false; //this was missing in your code.
    setProgress(newProgress);

    // Move to previous page
    setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
}
```

Comment: If my answer was helpful, you can support by marking it as the accepted answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

try changing the following

```
setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1)
```

to

```
setCurrentPage((page) => page + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If think you should have the += operator in setCurrentPage

```
 setCurrentPage(currentPage += 1);
```

the same in the setCurrentPage -=

```
setCurrentPage(currentPage -= 1);
```